# Integrating Activiti workflow to an existing project

Tags: activiti

We have an already existing project which does not rely on any workflow solution. For some recent feature requests we are planning to integrate workflow and considering to use Alfresco Activiti. There are some challenges we are facing as we are researching this solution. Most of them are related to integrating Activiti with our existing UI and database entities. I have listed the challenges below. Any suggestions or if you have already solved something similar will be highly appreciated

- We already have users setup in our own custom table (we don't use LDAP). And I see Activiti has it's own concept of users and group and task assignment works based on that. We would like Activiti to make use of the users in our custom table so that we can leverage the task assignment etc. without duplicating the users data

  - I see we can define forms in activiti for a user task. As this is our existing project we want to have more control on the forms using our custom layout. Is this something possible ?
  - We have some complex UI screens (to be User Tasks) where we have to populate list of options from our existing data sets. And then user makes a selection and select couple of items from this drop down and then based on business logic and items selected, we need to show additional yes/no options to user on the same screen. I did not see any option to design this type of dynamic UI in the Activiti forms and that is the reason we are also inclined to use custom approach to handle forms but also need to make sure we leverage Activiti in a way it adds value
  - We have a requirement around custom reporting for our use case. So what ever data we are capturing on various screen we would like to store it in our custom tables. Also this data also signify potential process variables which we require for conditional activiti expressions to route the workflow. Is there a way to refer this custom database entities to be used as process variable e.g. customer.name where customer is the entity we stored in database on very first screen

Comment: Yup, all seems doable

Comment: Is that existing project on Alfresco?

Comment: No it's not an Alfresco project as of now. A correction to my previous post, we are planning to use community version of Activiti.